# Can we add Internal Testers if we enrolled to Apple Developer Program as an Individual?

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

Could be a duplicate question but I still couldn't find a clear answer. If we sign up for the Apple Developer Program as an Individual instead of an Organization, can we add multiple users in iTunes connect? Simply the requirement is to add Internal testers to the Application as we do if we enroll as an Organization (Do we have a User and Access section on Individual Developer Program)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add internal testers to TestFlight even with an individual account type.

Comment: What are the user roles available in Individual account type?

Comment: The same as in an organisational account, but you cannot assign access to "certificates, profiles and identifiers"